# Should I use a CMS or custom built site?

Tags: asp.net, content-management-system

I am new to web development but I want to make a site that is similar in functionality to digg.com where users can submit content and can vote up or down certain content. Based on this up/down vote, I would publish the popular content on the home page and throw away bad content.

My question is, will a CMS (like Umbraco) be a good choice for this type of site? Or should I do everything manually using Visual Studio and ASP.NET?

Thanks for any feedback.

Answer (score 2):

Why reinvent the wheel? Find a CMS that you like to work with and go with it. Unless you truly need to tweak every last bit of performance out of it and don't want a single line of code devoted to something not part of the site, it's a lot simpler to allow another team to take care of the "common core" of functionality that's common to most user-oriented websites.

Comment: Using a CMS is by far the best place to start.  Using a CMS doesn't stop you from learning anything.  You just learn differently and if you are really curious how feature x works, then look at the code to see how it works.  BUT you really don't want to spend all the time developing things that have been done before, especially in a feature rich site.

Comment: As it applies to learning, which I am not sure how much the OP is interested in, looking at code written by someone else is a far cry from actually coding.

Answer (score 2):

If you actually want to learn anything, you should definitely build your own.  Most of your time spent setting up and running a specific CMS will give you a bunch of knowledge that only applies to that software.  If you don't care about learning more about web development and just want your site running, use a CMS.